# Understanding DIG Output for electronics.stackexchange.com

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I am trying to understand the workings of the DNS. When I do `dig electronics.stackexchange.com`, I get the following response (truncated at the bottom for brevity):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> electronics.stackexchange.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2941
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 27

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;electronics.stackexchange.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
electronics.stackexchange.com. 288 IN   A   151.101.129.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 288 IN   A   151.101.193.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 288 IN   A   151.101.65.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 288 IN   A   151.101.1.69

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            96429   IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            96429   IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 12796   IN  A   192.5.6.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 12796   IN  A   192.33.14.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 12796   IN  A   192.26.92.30
...
```

We can see that all authoritative servers for this domain are TLD `.com` server. I am a bit suprised that `stackexchange.com` does not have its own authoritative NS? So my question is, is there any specific reason why orgs might do this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your DNS server return you odd answer. One ordinary DNS will return to you answer like this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4 <<>> electronics.stackexchange.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61351
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;electronics.stackexchange.com. IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
electronics.stackexchange.com. 87 IN    A       151.101.1.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 87 IN    A       151.101.65.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 87 IN    A       151.101.193.69
electronics.stackexchange.com. 87 IN    A       151.101.129.69

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
stackexchange.com.      172587  IN      NS      ns-1832.awsdns-37.co.uk.
stackexchange.com.      172587  IN      NS      ns-925.awsdns-51.net.
stackexchange.com.      172587  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
stackexchange.com.      172587  IN      NS      ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
```

where you can see the name servers of domain `stackexchange.com.`